# Filter pandas DataFrame through list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filter

I have DataFrame of arbitrary length, with X columns (lets say 10):

```
>>> names = ['var_' + str(x) for x in range(1, 11)]
>>> names
['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4', 'var_5', 'var_6', 'var_7', 'var_8', 'var_9', 'var_10']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10,10)), columns = names)
>>> df
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4  var_5  var_6  var_7  var_8  var_9  var_10
0     39     49      6     39     16     41      8     86     23      52
1      6     16     21     20     81     97     83     25     56      73
2     72     97     43     50     10     46     22     75      7      18
3     20     35     69     59     14     24     57     31     47      20
4     39     93     45     80     74     87     83     50     52      67
5     93     75     83     67     40     46     79     11     31      95
6     75     76     57     82     69     98     74     75     93      13
7     35     19     28     67     39     23     72     16     63      67
8     93     87     52     25     63     29     46     64     78      12
9     81     43      4     90     88     64      1     83     26      22
```

Now i want to filter this DataFrame rowwise using list of dicts:

```
>>> test_dict_1 = {'var_1': 89, 'var_2': 12, 'var_3': 34}
>>> test_dict_2 = {'var_7': 3, 'var_2': 11, 'var_4': 19, 'var_1': 9}
>>> test_dict_3 = {'var_3': 31}
>>> filter = [test_dict_1, test_dict_2, test_dict_3]
```

To have something as result (dict? DataFrame? few DataFrames?), that contains only those rows with at least one of the filter passed (i.e. all of variables are same values in row as in filter). Besides that i ofcourse need to know which filters passed.

I'm quite new to pandas, so i'm a bit confused if i can do it without "for" loops. Any solutions please?

I know about chain solutions like df[(df.A == 1) & (df.D == 6)], but is it somehow possible to have few different filters?
Final goal is to have every row flagged with filters passed, without loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get it right, but if you want to filter your dataframe by few criteria from a dictionnary you could do something like this :

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]: 
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4  var_5  var_6  var_7  var_8  var_9  var_10
0     45     36     84     24     86     26     44      6     44      15
1     72     16     67     75     87     89      8     68     32      49
2      9     49      0      4     77     75     65      9     45      70

test_dict_1 = {'var_1': 72, 'var_2': 16, 'var_3': 67}

cond = True
for var in test_dict_1.keys():
    cond = cond & (df[var] == test_dict_1[var])
    df = df.loc[cond]
```

then you'll get :

```
In [109]: df
Out[109]: 
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4  var_5  var_6  var_7  var_8  var_9  var_10
1     72     16     67     75     87     89      8     68     32      49
```

Comment: Thats for one dict, and yes, i mentioned this solution in my question. Im talking about filtering with list of dicts, ie with few similar dicts. I think i have to use loop though.